# How to create a regression model object from intercept and coefficients values only (without the database) in R

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling

I want to recreate a regression model based on what was given in a scientific paper. They gave intercept and coefficient terms.

I know how to create regression models in R, but is this possible to do without the original database?

I would use these models on my own database to perform model comparison and test their predictive capabilities.

The special case here is that I am mostly interested in logistic regression. But I guess this question is scalable to all types of regression models.

So in other words: how can we create regression model objects (e.g. `glm`) using only `beta` values.

Comment: A working example of doing this with a logistic regression model, starting with the coefficients only, appears in the first block of code at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40609/919.  An example with Poisson models is at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/45789/919.  Note that at a minimum you will also need somehow to specify the values of the independent variables.

Comment: Related SO question that didn't get any answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703403/build-standard-r-model-objects-from-parameters. Building the P(Y=1) function from coefficients is one thing but embedding it in a standard R object is another. I have reached the conclusion that it is not something you want to achieve. A standard R model object will allow you to use a lot of functions but most of them will give you bad results because the glm model contain a lot more informations : Std. Error, z value, Pr(>|z|) for coefficients.

Comment: This does not appear to me to be possible.  The regression model includes more information than just the coefficient estimators (e.g., leverage values, standard errors, etc.).  For a linear model, the output is fully determined by the correlation matrix for all the vectors in the model plus the norms of those vectors.  Thus, if you don't have access to the original data, you would still need to have this information to generate the full regression output.  (Of course, you can generate *parts* of the regression output ---e.g., regression line--- with incomplete information.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You lack information about the values of the explanatory variables.** Exploring this issue reveals some useful things to know about logistic regression.  For instance, you can go far beyond simple rules of thumb concerning how much data you need for estimating the parameters and you can develop a better intuition for what can and cannot be accomplished depending on simple characteristics of the dataset (sizes, locations, and ranges).

---

**Let me explain with some examples.**  These scatterplots show data generated with the coefficients $\beta = (1,1)$ (and the usual logistic link) for various sets of $x$ values.  That is, the log odds of the expected response $y$ is $\beta_1 + \beta_2 x = 1 + x.$  (**This is fully general,** because *every* univariate logistic regression has this form when you choose suitable units of measurement for $x.$)

[image]

**To appreciate these plots,** understand that

- **The datasets are all the same size,** with $n = 100$ observations each.
- **The $x$ values** are equally spaced across their ranges.
- **The responses ($y$ values)** of $0$ and $1$ have been vertically jittered to avoid overplotting.
- **The gray curves** are all parts of the same model with $\beta=(1,1)$ used to generate the data.  They show how the chance of a response equal to $1$ varies with $x.$
- **The posted equations** are the *fitted* logistic models to each dataset in the form "$\hat\beta_0(\operatorname{se}(\hat\beta_0))\ + \hat\beta_1(\operatorname{se}(\hat\beta_1))x:$" that is, the standard errors of estimate appear in parentheses after each estimated parameter.  (The fits were computed with the `glm` function in `R`.)

**Observe how different these datasets appear.**  They differ in the ranges and locations of the $x$ values:

1. The **ranges** across the top in examples 1 through 4 are all equal to $2$ but the locations are shifted to right as you go from left to right.
2. The **locations** across the bottom in examples 5 through 8 are all centered at $x=0$ but the ranges increase from $2$ to $20.$

Consequently, most of these datasets cover small and very different portions of the full logistic sigmoidal curve, as illustrated by the gray curves.  That's how they manage to have such different appearances.  (But, as you can check by inspection, all coefficient estimates are within a couple of standard errors of the true model coefficients $\beta = (1,1).$)

---

**A *very* close examination of the standard errors will reveal a general truth:** the standard errors are smallest when most of the logistic curve is included, as in examples 7 and 8, and is largest when the curve varies only a little, as in examples 1 (the left tail), 4 (the right tail), and even 5 (the middle).  This implies you can get some hints about the likely $x$ values from the p-values reported in the paper, provided you know how many $x$ values are involved (which is usually the case): *caeteris paribus,* tiny p-values suggest you're in a situation like examples 6 through 8 while large p-values indicate otherwise.

(This gets much more complicated with multiple regression because the p-values depend on the geometric relationships among the various explanatory variables, making it unlikely you could infer much about the $x$ values used in the paper.)

Now (returning to the simple logistic regression case with a single explanatory variable), **if** you can estimate the range of the $x$ values and the number of $x$ values, **you can simulate sample data by generating likely values of $x$ and drawing random binomial responses according to the model.**  This is illustrated in the first block of `R` code at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40609/919, but to be fully explicit I offer this general-purpose implementation (used to create the plots).

```r
#
# Generate data according to a specified logistic regression model.
# `x` are the explanatory values (which can be a matrix for multiple regression).
# `beta` are the coefficients.
# When `intercept` is TRUE, beta[1] is taken to be the intercept term.
#
# Returns a matrix of `n` columns, one for each independent data set.
#
rlreg <- function(n = 1, beta, x, intercept = TRUE) {
  if(isTRUE(intercept)) x <- cbind(1, x)
  if (!is.matrix(x)) x <- matrix(x, ncol = length(beta))

  y.hat <- x %*% beta        # The inverse link values
  h <- 1 / (1 + exp(-y.hat)) # The expectations
  matrix(rbinom(n * length(h), 1, h), ncol = n)
}
```

As an example of the use of `rlreg`, here are three independent simulated datasets sharing a common set of $x$ values (leftmost column).

```r
set.seed(17)
df <- data.frame(x = seq(-4, 4, length.out = 9))
df$y <- rlreg(3, c(1, 1), df$x)
df
```

```
   x y.1 y.2 y.3
1 -4   0   0   0
2 -3   1   0   0
3 -2   0   0   1
4 -1   1   1   1
5  0   1   0   0
6  1   1   0   1
7  2   1   1   1
8  3   1   1   1
9  4   1   1   1
```

Comment: Great and detailed answer. Thank you.

Comment: thanks whuber: would you pls also share the r script graphic output part?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is "score" (create a new column in your database that contains the predicted values for each record in your database) using the regression model coefficients and functional form of the model (for linear regression example, y = XB where y is the predicted value from the regression model, X is your database, and B is a vector with the model coefficients).

I'm not sure of the exact functional form of your regression model but in R you can write the equation from the command line:

> y <- a + b*x

Hope this helps

Comment: http://statistics.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm

Comment: Link to R code in previous comment

Comment: The question focuses on GLMs, for which this approach will not work.  For linear regression your model is incomplete: you need to add random noise to `y`.  Its variance is one more parameter of the model.

Comment: Agree if goal is simulating draws from model distribution. Prior post predicts model mean for a given set of covariates.